# Why are there blue arrows on the dots in the Manim ArrowVectorField?

Tags: manim

I don't know why this vector field draws blue arrows on the dots the field is built around. I assume its because of the function generator, but I don't understand it well enough to see why it would generate them or what it means in the vector field. The documentation on ArrowVectorField did not address this issue.

[image]

The picture shows the small blue arrows on the center dot and on the other three attractor states.

```py
# function generator
# https://github.com/3b1b/videos/blob/436842137ee6b89cbb2aa10fa2d4c2e12361dac8/_2018/div_curl.py#L100
def get_force_field_func(*point_strength_pairs, **kwargs):
    radius = kwargs.get("radius", 0.5)

    def func(point):
        result = np.array(ORIGIN)
        for center, strength in point_strength_pairs:
            to_center = center - point
            norm = np.linalg.norm(to_center)
            if norm == 0:
                continue
            elif norm < radius:
                to_center /= radius**3
            elif norm >= radius:
                to_center /= norm**3
            to_center *= -strength
            result += to_center
        return result
    return func
```

```py
class Test(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        progenitor = Dot()
        self.add(progenitor)

        attractor1 = Dot().move_to(RIGHT * 2 + UP * 3)
        attractor2 = Dot().move_to(UP * 2 + LEFT * 4)
        attractor3 = Dot().move_to(DOWN * 2 + RIGHT * 4)

        constrained_func = get_force_field_func(
            (progenitor.get_center(), 1),
            (attractor1.get_center(), -0.5),
            (attractor2.get_center(), -2),
            (attractor3.get_center(), -1)
        )

        constrained_field = ArrowVectorField(constrained_func)
        self.add(constrained_field)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the return value of your `generator_function` at these values, for example at the origin:

```
>>> constrained_func(np.array([0, 0, 0]))
array([-0.02338674,  0.05436261,  0.        ])
```

This is a small vector pointing to the top left -- which is exactly what the small blue arrow in the origin is.

If you'd like to get rid of that, you could replace `continue` with `return np.array([0., 0., 0.])` -- but that might not be in line with the concept modeled by the generator function.